# Postgres array of JSON avoid casting

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

Issuing on PostgresSQL 9.2 the following:

```
CREATE TABLE test (j JSON, ja JSON[]);
INSERT INTO test (j) VALUES('{"name":"Alex", "age":20}' ); -- Works FINE
INSERT INTO test (ja) VALUES( ARRAY['{"name":"Alex", "age":20}', '{"name":"Peter", "age":24}'] ); -- Returns ERROR
```

The first insert works fine.
The second insert returns error: *column "ja" is of type json[] but expression is of type text[]*

I can cast type to prevent the error:

```
INSERT INTO test(ja) VALUES( CAST (ARRAY['{"name":"Alex", "age":20}', '{"name":"Peter", "age":24}'] as JSON[]) ); -- Works FINE
```

My question is if there is a way to avoid casting?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
insert into test(ja) values
('{"{\"name\":\"alex\", \"age\":20}", "{\"name\":\"peter\", \"age\":24}"}');
```

To avoid the confuse escaping cast each string:

```
insert into test(ja) values
(array['{"name":"alex", "age":20}'::json, '{"name":"peter", "age":24}'::json]);
```

Or just cast the array itself:

```
insert into test (ja) values
(array['{"name":"alex", "age":20}', '{"name":"peter", "age":24}']::json[]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, especially the second form.

Comment: can you please answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51571453/query-to-insert-array-of-json-object-into-postgres?noredirect=1#comment90997752_51571453