# Query to insert array of json object into postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with field `fields json[]`. I have created a function to insert the record into that table and here is the call

```
select * from add('[{"name":"Yes","value":"yes"},{"name":"No","value":"no"},{"name":"Neutral","value":"neutral"}]') as result;
```

and here is the function itself

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.add(
    _fields json[]) RETURNS SETOF json 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
     DECLARE
        query text;
    BEGIN
        insert into my_table(fields)
          values(_fields);
        query = 'SELECT json_build_object(''message'', ''Added.'')';
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE query; 
        END;
$BODY$;
```

but this is showing

```
malformed array literal: "[{"name":"Yes","value":"yes"},{"name":"No","value":"no"},{"name":"Neutra
```

then I tried this

```
select * from add('{"name":"Yes","value":"yes"},{"name":"No","value":"no"},{"name":"Neutral","value":"neutral"}') as result;
```

and this insert statement in function like

```
insert into polls(fields) values(array([''||_fields||'']::json[]));
```

and this is showing

```
syntax error at or near "["
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but what is the function result type? is it missing in the declaration?

Comment: @Jay updated the question to add return type

Comment: `json[]` essentially never makes sense. Use a single JSON value that itself contains an array

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name then how can i insert same data if i make it to `jsonb ` object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing `"` for each individual object. This is how to create json object

```
{"{\"name\":\"Yes\",\"value\":\"yes\"}","{\"name\":\"No\",\"value\":\"no\"}","{\"name\":\"Neutral\",\"value\":\"neutral\"}"}
```

so the final query is

```
select * from add('{"{\"name\":\"Yes\",\"value\":\"yes\"}","{\"name\":\"No\",\"value\":\"no\"}","{\"name\":\"Neutral\",\"value\":\"neutral\"}"}') as result;
```